# Request data from Linkedin

Tags: python, json, api, http, python-requests

I have Problem with scraping data from LinkedIn.
I think the documentation is too complicated ...
here the problem, I want to make a request (GET) and get for example data of my feed/posts/chats or whatever.

here is my code:

```
import json 
import requests


# URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/voyagerMessagingDashConversationNudges"
URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/identity/dash/profiles"

cookies = {
   #Cookies are here
}

params = {
    'decorationId': 'com.linkedin.voyager.dash.deco.identity.profile.WebTopCardCore-6',
    'memberIdentity': 'maria-albert-137632240',
    'q': 'memberIdentity',
}

def get_group(url: str, cookies: dict, data:dict, header: dict):
    response = requests.get(url=url, cookies=cookies, data=json.dumps(data), headers=header)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("sending request to Server:\n")
    get_group(url=URL, cookies=cookies, data=params, header=headers)
```

but I couldn't do it, the error --> `raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: INKApi Error for url: https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/identity/dash/profiles`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do not post cookies values in here unless you want your data stolen!

Comment: and you have typos in "Accept" headers

Comment: @vladtkachuk yea u r right, but this account is just used for this purpose, there is no data

Comment: thx I fixed that, but the error still exists. :(

Comment: First of all, change `data=json.dumps(data)` to `params=data`, and if you're requesting directly to the API, you should send some token or secret to get access.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan I changed it, how should I POST access token ?
documentation is so bad...
just confused me!

Comment: You should [create an app](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth/token-generator) and use the [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-06) to make requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set header like this:

```
header = {
    "accept": 'application/vnd.linkedin.normalized+json+2.1',
    "cookie": 'JSESSIONID="ajax:abcd"; li_at=abcdabcd',
}
```

and so fill the payload as the endpoint needed.
You **don't have to** Create App to access token or anything else.